# VIM uses wrong encoding - but only in status messages

Tags: vim, arch-linux, encoding, unicode, character-encoding

I ran into a strange issue with my ArchLinux setup. Vim uses correct encoding for reading/displaying files but these status messages (which displays the current mode or reports back when the buffer is written to a file) uses a wrong encoding for the (Hungarian) message.

I tried to set termencoding=utf-8 but it does not solve the issue. The encoding is correctly set to utf-8. The MATE Terminal is also in UTF-8 and my locale is also in UTF-8:

```
LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="hu_HU.UTF-8"
```

I currently ran out of ideas, please help me out.

[image]

Comment: As a non-hungarian speaker, everything looks normal to me in that screenshot ;-).

Comment: @romainl the status line should be "-- BESZÚR --" :)

Comment: As this bug is also arrived in ubuntu, I was looking for a most recent (or previous working) `vim.mo`. No luck. Maybe compiling it from git would solve the issue, but I didn't want that much fuss, so just deleted the `vim.mo` from `/usr/share/locale-langpack/hu/LC_MESSAGES`. Now my gvim menu is still in hungarian (it comes from elsewhere), and no translations in the status line, which is far more better than the one with bad encoding. By the way my ubuntu is 22.04, vim version is 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to know your vim version...

In my hypothesis, it came with vim 9.1.

You can file a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) or ask directly the maintainer of [hu.po](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/po/hu.po) file whether he can help to find out what went wrong in this case.

Another alternative is to wait until somehow it become magically solved -- but this is my way, and I don't recommend this approach for any daily user of vim!

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Jan 02 2024 18:36:25)

Comment: Btw, the PO file itself is in UTF-8 so in theory it sould be good.

Comment: @GaborGarami the utf8 change appears on yesterday, see history: https://github.com/vim/vim/commits/master/src/po/hu.po
In the package the po file is in iso-8859-1 (see https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/0efa58184b9e60a66eb51a09a51eec81fbfaeb6d/src/po/hu.po ).

I think it should be right in the next version (or manually install the utf8 po file).

Comment: Yeah I saw it I just did not had a time to update this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @folti it magically became solved :P